# Set an icon for apk file (not android app icon. Desk top icon for a apk file)

Tags: android, react-native, apk

Is there any way to set an icon for apk file. I am not talking about the app icon showing in the mobile. The icon for apk file to show in the desktop explorer.

[image]

Comment: you can do this: [How-to-Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13631/customize-your-icons-in-windows-7-and-vista/)

Comment: But, i need this icon application specific. like one icon for one application. is there any config available in android manifest.